# Loop on front-page.php

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop, frontpage

I'm trying to load the 3 latests posts on my homepage. I'm an utter novice but I *seem* to be making progress.

This is my code (below). At the minute each post has a title of "Home", I understand that is because the homepage is the main query?

```
<?php
    $latest_blog_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
    if ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $latest_blog_posts->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop');
    endwhile; endif;
?>
```

So how would I amend this code so it pulls in the 3 latest posts from the blog using loop.php?

I also having a Custom Post Type which uses a different page/loop. But I assume once this is working it would just be a matter of swapping the 'loop' for 'loop-2' to get that working using the same code?

Hope someone can help with this. It's one step forward, two steps back at the minute for me!

**EDIT**

Contents of `loop.php` as requested in reply :)

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="h-entry__image-link">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->

        <!-- post title -->
        <h2 class="p-name">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
        <!-- /post title -->

        <!-- post details -->
        <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" class="dt-published"><?php the_time('jS F Y'); ?></time>
        <!-- /post details -->

        <?php html5wp_summary('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="arrow-link">Read the full article</a></p>

        <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the output happens via the template file **loop.php** - so we need to know the full code of that file to be able to say anything...

Comment: the problem is that **loop.php** contains the full code of the default loop, so your custom query before calling the **loop.php** willl never work. you will possibly need to edit your **front-page.php** file and add your output code - html and php - instead of `get_template_part('loop');`

Comment: That makes sense and confirms what I feared. Nothings ever simple is it haha! So the code from loop.php would be copied and pasted onto the homepage, so you'd essentially have the same markup in 2 locations?

Comment: I've been told I can use `wp_reset_query();` to reset the Wordpress query after looping through a custom query so that it reverts back to the default query for the current page. Does that sound right or will it not work with my loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would do it.  You're loop is based on being in an archive or index page. (or home)

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post_type'     => 'post',  //choose post type here
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop');
    endwhile; 
else :

endif;
```

revised code running full query without the content-part.php

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post_type'     => 'post',  //choose post type here
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
?>
        <!-- article -->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <!-- post thumbnail -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="h-entry__image-link">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- /post thumbnail -->

    <!-- post title -->
    <h2 class="p-name">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <!-- /post title -->

    <!-- post details -->
    <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" class="dt-published"><?php the_time('jS F Y'); ?></time>
    <!-- /post details -->

    <?php html5wp_summary('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="arrow-link">Read the full article</a></p>

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

</article>
<!-- /article -->
<?php
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

i can't fully test it because of the functions being called by your theme, but try it out.

If this does work you you can pull out the article content.  Replace all the content in your current loop.php with the content above but only from

```
<!-- article -->
```

to

```
<!-- /article -->
```

Since that would be in your new loop.php, you'll take it out of the main page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this but it just lists 3 blog posts all with the title "Home" and any links just link to the homepage. :/

Comment: in your dashboard under settings  do you have your home page set as blog posts or some other page.  you'll want to make sure homepage is not set as blog.

Comment: also just saw your loop.  Putting those two files together you are running 2 loops inside each other.  That is more likely the problem.  Did you create the code on the homepage?  Pull the content of the loop out and put on the homepage

Comment: I thought about doing that but then would I need to maintain the loop markup in 2 different locations? Not really a biggie for this project, especially as it's my first dabble into Wordpress. yeah the code is just in front-page.php so I've dropped in the code I need like header/footer and also some Advanced Custom Field markup.

Comment: I've been told I can use `wp_reset_query();` to reset the Wordpress query after looping through a custom query so that it reverts back to the default query for the current page. Does that sound right or will it not work with my loop?

Comment: Okay i'm going to post the whole code above.  Try the new one.

Comment: Cool thanks, so all this code goes on front-page.php? Seems to work! What do you mean the "content-part.php"?

I take it there's no other way than to duplicate the code from loop.php and paste it onto front-page.php?

Comment: you can.  see end of my question above.

Comment: Thanks, I can't give this a shot now but I will do asap. So essentially you remove the `<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
` reference yeah? Someone told me that was causing the problem and to load posts from your custom query I'd need to call the functions from my query. For example `$latest_blog_posts-> if_have_posts (), $latest_blog_posts-> while_have_posts () and $latest_blog_posts-> the_post()` not sure if that matches what you've done?

Comment: Hey man, that's great and I removed everything from loop.php apart from the actual `<article>` and used your `$args` code to pull 3 posts onto the homepage! Now only 1 displays on the actual Blog page ...but I guess I just need to put the code I removed from the loop.php around the `<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>` on the Blog page to rectify that?

Comment: that or check your settings/readings page and see how many you're showing there.  Mind marking as answered?

Comment: Sure, you've been a massive help! Do you mean settings/readings within the CMS? When I didn't wrap the loop in the code I removed (if/else statement) in archive.php (for example), it only displayed one post. Adding the `have_posts` if statement at the start and adding the closing else statement after the loop seemed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $latest_blog_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'offset' => 3 ) );
    if ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $latest_blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $latest_blog_posts->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop');
    endwhile; endif;
?>
```

For more information about WP Query with custom parameters check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question? Offset will show posts 4,5,6 not 'the 3 Latest posts'

Comment: Unfortunately that just creates posts that are titled "Home" and link to the front-page.php as well :/